# Access the children from the QScrollArea

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have added a QScrollArea widget in QDialog form.

In the scrollarea, I have added 16 chcekboxes.

I want to loop inside the scrollarea and check for which of the checkboxes are checked.

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in advance!

The code for ScrollArea and Checkbox is like this:

```
<widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>320</y>
     <width>271</width>
     <height>206</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="widgetResizable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width>252</width>
      <height>420</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox1">
       <property name="text">
        <string>1</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="7" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox7">
       <property name="text">
        <string>2</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="5" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox5">
       <property name="text">
        <string>3</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="2" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox2">
       <property name="text">
        <string>4</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="0" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox0">
       <property name="text">
        <string>5</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="3" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox3">
       <property name="text">
        <string>6</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="6" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox6">
       <property name="text">
        <string>7</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="4" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox4">
       <property name="text">
        <string>8</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="12" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox12">
       <property name="text">
        <string>9</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="10" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox10">
       <property name="text">
        <string>10</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="11" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox11">
       <property name="text">
        <string>11</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="9" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox9">
       <property name="text">
        <string>Signal Mask</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="8" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox8">
       <property name="text">
        <string>12</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="15" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox15">
       <property name="text">
        <string>13</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="14" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox14">
       <property name="text">
        <string>14</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="13" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox13">
       <property name="text">
        <string>15</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="16" column="0">
      <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox16">
       <property name="text">
        <string>16</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with the [QObject::findChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChildren) method.

An example code in your `.cpp` file that belongs to the `.ui` file would look like this:

```
QList<QCheckBox *> allCheckBoxes = this->findChildren<QCheckBox *>();

for (QCheckBox *checkBox: allCheckBoxes) {
   if (checkBox->isChecked()) {
      qDebug() << "CheckBox with object name " << checkBox->objectName() << " is checked";
   }
}
```